# Codeigniter Session Sets 2nd time during login

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
   class Login_model extends CI_Model {
   public function login() {
        $username = $_POST['uname'];
        $password = $_POST['pw'];
        $query = $this->db->get_where('test_logins', array('name' => $username, 'password' => $password));
        $count = $query->num_rows() > 0;
        if ($count == 1) {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                 $exam_id=$row['id'];
            }
            $query2 = $this->db->get_where('candidates', array('email' =>$_POST['email']));
            $count2=$query2->num_rows();
            //echo($count2);
            if($count2==1){

                foreach ($query2->result_array() as $row2)
                {
                 $candidate_id=$row2['id'];
                 $part1=$row2['part1'];
                 $part2=$row2['part2'];
                 $part3=$row2['part3'];
                 $part4=$row2['part4'];
                }
                //set session
                $newdata1 = array(
                                    'username' => $username,
                                    'exam_id'=> $exam_id,
                                    'candidate_id'=> $candidate_id,
                                    'logged_in' => TRUE
                                 );
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata1);
                if(empty($part1)){
                    return 'part1';
                }else if(empty($part2)){
                    return 'part2';
                }else if(empty($part3)){
                    return 'part3';
                }else if(empty($part4)){
                    return 'part4';
                }
            }else{
            $data = array(
                               'name' => $_POST['name'],
                               'email' => $_POST['email'],
                               'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                               'contact' => $_POST['mobile'],
                         );
                               $this->db->insert('candidates', $data);
                               $candidate_id=$this->db->insert_id();
            $newdata = array(
                'username' => $username,
                'exam_id'=> $exam_id,
                'candidate_id'=> $candidate_id,
                'logged_in' => TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            return 'part1';
            }//else insert candidate

        }else {
            return FALSE;
        }

    }
  }
?>
```

Checking if Login id and password is correct. If yes then checking if user is already registered for exam or not, if registered user creating session then checking which part of exam remaining and redirecting to that parts controller, if not registered creating a record and creating session then redirecting to 1st part of exam, But session is always null on 1st attempt and gets set from 2nd attempt.

Comment: why you are writing $count = $query->num_rows() > 0; instead of if($query->num_rows() > 0) {} else {}, and your whole coding structure.

Answer (score 0):

The code you mentioned in question having some flaws so i write it clean and in a codeigniter way here plz try this and let me know then. I was unable to put this whole code as comment so write it as an answer :)

```
<?php

class Login_model extends CI_Model {

    public function login() 
    {
        $username = $this->input->post['uname'];
        $password = $this->input->post['pw'];
        $exam_id  = 0;
        $candidate_id = 0;

        $query = $this->db->get_where('test_logins', array(
            'name' => $username, 
            'password' => $password
        ));

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            $row = $query->row();
            if (isset($row)) 
            {
                $exam_id = $row->id;
            }

            $query2 = $this->db->get_where('candidates', array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email')
            ));

            if ($query2->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                $row2 = $query2->row();
                if (isset($row2)) 
                {
                    $candidate_id = $row2->id;
                    $part1        = $row2->part1;
                    $part2        = $row2->part2;
                    $part3        = $row2->part3;
                    $part4        = $row2->part4;
                }

                if(empty($part1)) { return 'part1'; } 
                else if(empty($part2)) { return 'part2'; } 
                else if(empty($part3)) { return 'part3'; } 
                else if(empty($part4)) { return 'part4'; }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->insert('candidates', array(
                    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                    'contact' => $this->input->post('mobile')
                ));

                return 'part1';
            }

            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'username' => $username,
                'exam_id'=> $exam_id,
                'candidate_id'=> $candidate_id,
                'logged_in' => TRUE
            ));

        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```